# PHP/Ajax Pause subsequent request until current request is completed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, queue

In my project, you can activate several created task by toggling an activation switch.

[image]

problem is, if I toggle two switches say ON in quick succession, only the last one get successfully completed.

How do I implement some waiting mechanism such that the ajax request for subsequent activation is pending until the previous ones are completed before they are fired?

Comment: What is your current code? What have you tried?

Comment: This is simliar to what your looking for -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done?rq=1

Comment: It's not similar because there is only one function that listen to the change event on the toggle/switch and the fire the ajax request.

Comment: @Collizo4sky does your console show all those requests? i mean are you sure triggering all those request at once are not aborting all the requests but the last?

Comment: Console show all request are being sent and none is aborting.

I just want a delay mechanism that put subsequent requests on hold until current one is completed.

Comment: You could send the values of all the switches with every ajax request, then it doesn't matter if only the last request gets processed by the server

Comment: @miknik Exactly what I thought of doing last night. Great suggestion.